# How does jquery do their releases?

Tags: jquery, git, bower

When I look at the latest commit from a tagged release, that commit seems to be lost from the master branch. Are they deleting their commits after they have pushed the tags?

If you look [at the last commit from tag:v1.11.1](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commits/1.11.1) it's `1.11.`.

[image]

But, when I go find that commit from `1.x-master` [I cannot find it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commits/1.x-master?page=2).

[image]

This must be some kind of sorcery.

Answer (score 0):

They don't delete it, the commit is just simply not on the master branch. Maybe they create a temporary branch on the release server, do the commit, tag it and just push the tag to the repository.